# Matching the regex with the item in list of dict values and if matches then store another value of the dictionary in a nested list

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose we have a List of dictionary items like this below:-

```
items_list = [{message:Hello There!, name: Smriti, ts:123456}, {message:Hello There!,name: Simran, ts:56789},{message:Heya, name: Pankhuri, ts:897652}]
```

If regex "Hello" in message[value] then store ts[val] in a list.
So my output should be : list of items with ts[val] only if it matches the message[val] to regex "Hello"

```
Output_list = [ 123456, 56789]
```

I have tried the following way as shown in below code :

```
import re


items_list = [{"message":"Hello There!", "name": "Smriti", "ts":123456},{"message":"Hello There!","name": "Simran", "ts":56789},{"message":"Heya"," name": "Pankhuri", "ts":897652}]
data = []
for item in items_list:
    if re.match(".*Hello", item['message']):
        data.append(item)
data_ts = [item['ts'] for item in data]
print(data_ts)
```

Is there any better way of doing this ? Appreciate for any good suggestions.

Comment: Could you show what you tried so far ? And explain what problems you got while trying to do it ?

Comment: I have updated the code which gives me the same output as i requested but i think it looks a more complex so thought if there is any better way of doing that.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this

```py
items_list = [{"message":"Hello There!", "name": "Smriti", "ts":123456},{"message":"Hello There!","name": "Simran", "ts":56789},{"message":"Heya"," name": "Pankhuri", "ts":897652}]

result = [item["ts"] for item in items_list if re.match(".*Hello", item["message"])]
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works in a single-liner better style code. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

as you said in the comments:

> but I think it looks a more complex so thought if there is any better way of doing that.

The easiest way to achieve your goal without using regex:

```
items_list = [{"message":"Hello There!", "name": "Smriti", "ts":123456}, {"message":"Hello There!","name": "Simran", "ts":56789},{"message":"Heya", "name": "Pankhuri", "ts":897652}]


data_ts = [item['ts'] for item in items_list if "Hello" in item['message']]
print(data_ts)
```

This gives me:

```
[123456, 56789]
```

---

**Additional Note:**
And if you want to get rid of case sensitivity, You can use `.upper()` like this:

```
data_ts = [item['ts'] for item in items_list if "Hello".upper() in item['message'].upper()]
```